# GuestAdditions on Loki

Tags: release-loki, settings

yesterday I installed Loki in my VirtualBox. Like with Freya and Luna, I could not use full screen or copy/paste from windows with the clean install, so I tried to install the guestAdditions. But in this case, it also did not work (in fact this time resolution was far worse).

Any clue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Question is about a release or feature that has been significantly updated, to the point at which upgrading fixes the issue or answers the question.